# Can't able to run react-native-maps in my Project

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I am trying to install react-native-maps in my project and followed the instructions given in the https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md. But still I am getting error after running my project in Android and it displays error of UIBlock which is present in the AirMapModule.java of react-native-maps in Android Studio. Can anyone help me regarding this?

Here are the versions of my project:

```
  "react": "16.6.1",
  "react-native": "^0.59.2",
  "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0"
```

Here is the error which I am getting :

````
                                   ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: package com.facebook.react.uimanager
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:129: error: getCurrentActivity() is not public in ReactContext; cannot be accessed from outside package
    if (!contextHasBug(appContext.getCurrentActivity())) {
                                 ^
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:130: error: getCurrentActivity() is not public in ReactContext; cannot be accessed from outside package
      superContext = appContext.getCurrentActivity();
                               ^
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
      if (!contextHasBug(reactContext.getCurrentActivity())) {
                                     ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: variable reactContext of type ThemedReactContext
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapView.java:134: error: cannot find symbol
        superContext = reactContext.getCurrentActivity();
                                   ^
  symbol:   method getCurrentActivity()
  location: variable reactContext of type ThemedReactContext
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\ViewAttacherGroup.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    this.setOverflow("hidden"); // Change to ViewProps.HIDDEN until RN 0.57 is base
        ^
  symbol: method setOverflow(String)
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapMarkerManager.java:127: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapMarkerManager.java:130: error: cannot find symbol
    super.setZIndex(view, zIndex);
         ^
  symbol: method setZIndex(AirMapMarker,float)
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapModule.java:90: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock() {
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapModule.java:149: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapModule.java:192: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapModule.java:229: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\AirMapModule.java:262: error: cannot find symbol
    uiManager.addUIBlock(new UIBlock()
                             ^
  symbol:   class UIBlock
  location: class AirMapModule
D:\Maps\Project\node_modules\react-native-maps\lib\android\src\main\java\com\airbnb\android\react\maps\RegionChangeEvent.java:15: error: no suitable constructor found for Event(int)
    super(id);
    ^
    constructor Event.Event() is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor Event.Event(int,long) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
14 errors```
````

Comment: can you show the code snippet or example?

Comment: Actually, the problem is not in the code, I am getting the error due to manually linking of react-native-maps in Android Studio as defined in the instructions in the above GitHub link. This error may be due to the current version of React-Native i.e 0.59.2 and I also checked https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2762 for the same but I am not sure whether this error is due to this reason. Have you got any error while installing react-native-maps in your own project?

Comment: No, I haven't face any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split your Maven dependancies as explained here:

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
```

}

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/issues/2090

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just wanted to know that in which version of React Native and React you were installing react-native-maps?